# Questionnaire Wizard in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

My requirement is to create a exam questionnaire wizard. The steps in wizard will be dynamically created.There will be some basic steps that will be common for some applicant like language settings etc. The questions will be generated depending on the type of exam selected by the applicant. There will be at least 25 to 35 questions per questionnaire that means there will be 35- 45 steps per wizard. I cannot save the answers in database. It has to be in session and I cannot use java script.

User should have easy accessibility. he can start answering exam in any order he wishes.

My approach was to create usercontrols for basic steps(like language,instruction and Question) and invoke it on the page as and when the link is clicked. I have just put a sample image from my test project.

[image]

Since the questions are dynamically fetched depending on applicant I will fetch all the question and create a list and display it using Question user control step by step.

I have created wizards many time in asp.net but not in MVC so I have some doubts.

Issues or Concern Facing:

Navigation button: NEXT and Previous. Can I put it in ASPX page instead of each user control page.

Assume that user has selected one link like say for eg Question 1 he has entered the answer and clicked on another link or NEXT Button how will i get the updated object with the answer user has selected. Since link doesn't have post action.

If you guys can suggest some ways of achieving this, it will be of great help.

**Below shown is my aspx page:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of MVCApp.WizardVM)" %>
<%@ Import Namespace ="MVCApp" %>
<asp:Content ID="indexTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Home Page
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<% Using Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home")%>

   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="menu" class="block">                  
                      <ul id="menuItems">              
                        <% For Each item As MVCApp.MenuVM In Model.menus%>       
                         <li><%: Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Index", "Home", New With {item.ID}, Nothing)%></li>                    
                        <%Next%>
                       </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <% Html.RenderPartial(Model.UserControlName, Model.Model)%>             


            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td colspan=2 align="right">
            <input type="submit" value="Next" />
            <input type="submit" value="Previous" />
        </td>
        </tr>
   </table>

 <% End Using %>        

</asp:Content>
```

**Controller Class:**

```
Public Class HomeController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller


    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Dim oWizard As New WizardVM
        oWizard = GetData()

        If (ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Count > 2) Then
            If (ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Item("ID") = 1) Then
                oWizard.UserControlName = "language"
                oWizard.Model = oWizard.Language

            ElseIf (ControllerContext.RouteData.Values.Item("ID") = 3) Then
                oWizard.UserControlName = "Question"
                oWizard.Model = oWizard.Question
            End If
        Else
            oWizard.UserControlName = "language"
            oWizard.Model = oWizard.Language
        End If

        Return View("index", oWizard)
    End Function

    Function About() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function


    Public Function GetData() As WizardVM
        Try
            Dim oWizard As New WizardVM

            Dim oLanaguage As New LanguageVM
            oLanaguage.Description = "This is a language test screen."
            oWizard.Language = oLanaguage


            Dim oQuestion As New QuestionVM
            oQuestion.Description = "This is a Question test screen."
            oWizard.Question = oQuestion

            Dim oMenus As New List(Of MenuVM)
            Dim oMenuHelper As New MenuHelper
            oMenus = oMenuHelper.BuildMenu()

            oWizard.menus = oMenus

            Return oWizard
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function


    <HttpPost()>
    Function GetLanguageInfo(ByVal oLanguage As LanguageVM) As ActionResult
        Dim a As Integer
        a = 10
        Return View("index")
    End Function
```

**My Model View Classes**

```
Public Class WizardVM

    Public Property SelectedMenuId As Integer
    Public Property Language As LanguageVM
    Public Property Question As QuestionVM

    Public menus As List(Of MenuVM)

    Public Property UserControlName As String
    Public Property Model As Object

End Class
```

**Language Model View Class**

```
Public Class LanguageVM

    Public Property Description As String

End Class
```

**Question ModelView Class**

```
Public Class QuestionVM
    Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

**UserControls:**

**LANUGAGE**

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl(of MVCApp.LanguageVM)" %>
<form method="post" action="/Home/GetLanguageInfo"> 
    <p>Description
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Description)%>
    </p>
</form>
```

Same way i have created for question. I cannot use javascript so i will have to replace links with buttons. but how will i handle the object post.

Answer (score 1):

You can make next and previous submit buttons. If you give them the same name (in code below I used "PageToGo") then you can add a corresponding string to your model with that name, and on submission you can determine which page to go to next.

As for the question links, if you need them to post answers I see only two solutions.

1) If you know javascript will be enabled, then upon any link clicks, either post the page with ajax then proceed to the link upon success, or save the links question number into your form then post the form.

If you do the latter idea you'd have something like

```
if(model.PageToGo == "Next")
   newPage = currentPage + 1;
else if(model.PageToGo == "Previous")
   newPage = currentPage - 1;
else
   newPage = int.Parse(model.PageToGo);
```

If you can't assume javascript is enabled, the only solution I can think of is to make all your links submit buttons and then make them look like links with css.

**Edit:** Looking at your new requirements/code, my advice is that language and questions should not use the same Action. Instead, have both of them inherit a base model that contains all your menu data, and create a shared view that both of them use that creates the menu of submit buttons.

It sounds like you're trying to partially submit a webpage the way you can partially submit Windows Forms. I don't know if that's possible, unless you use ajax/javascript. Using the method I described, you'll still be posting the entire page, but if you have different actions handling the posts of questions/ language, it will be easier to process each one.

Comment: I like the submit button with a link style solution. It's very easy to do and safe because you won't need javascript enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion guys it meant lot to me but when I was thinking on above mentioned solution I visualised problem in how I will handel a senario where once User has selected a "Language" link button. The user control will be loaded on right hand side in the screen as shown in sample image above. After selecting the language user clicks next button which is placed on ASPX page. Now the language object binded to language usercontrol is updated. How will the post action of user control be triggered as it will try to submit the main wizard page.  I have updated the code in question.

Comment: can you please give me an example or sample code. If I use submit button for menu how will i pass parameter to konw which menu is clicked by user. I cannot use javascript as javascript will be disabled on user screens.

Comment: @Vinod If you give the buttons different names, then only the button with the name you clicked will have a value submitted to the form. So you could do checks like Request["Question1"] != null